# SQL - How to verify that at least 1 keyword from a list of keywords exists in a field

Tags: c#, sql

I have a Keywords table with the fields KeywordsEn and KeywordsFr.
I have another MediaObjectsMetadata with the field Values.

I need to check that the Value field contains at least one of the words from the Keywords table (either in KeywordsEn or KeywordsFr field).

I thought I would use the Contains function like this, where @priorityKeywords contains all the KeywordsEn and KeywordsFr concatenated with OR, but then I have over 16000 characters in my string, and the Contains function can only allow 4000.

Part of my SP

```
SELECT FKMediaObjectId
FROM dbo.gs_MediaObjectMetadata
WHERE UPPER([Description]) = 'KEYWORDS'
AND FKMediaObjectId >= 
  (SELECT TOP 1 MediaObjectId 
  FROM dbo.gs_MediaObject 
  WHERE DateAdded > @lastcheck 
  ORDER BY MediaObjectId) 
  AND Contains([Value] , @priorityKeywords);
```

C# function which generates @priorityKeywords

```
public static string GetPriorityKeywordsList()
{
  string keywordString = String.Empty;

  using (IDataReader dr = GetCommandPriorityKeywordsList().ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
  {
    while (dr.Read())
    {
      if (keywordString.Length > 0)
      {
         keywordString += " OR ";
      }
      // max 4000 chars allowed in COntains sql function of sp
      keywordString += "'" + dr["KeywordEn"].ToString() + "' OR '" + dr["KeywordFr"].ToString() + "'";
     }
    }
        return keywordString;
}
```

What solution would you recommend for my stored procedure?

Edit (Solution):

Here is the solution proposed by Andomar, adapted to my situation:

```
select  *
from    gs_MediaObjectMetadata yt
where   
UPPER([Description]) = 'KEYWORDS'
AND  not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    dbo.fnSplit(Replace(yt.Value, '''', ''''''), ',') split
        where   split.item in (select KeywordEn from gs_Keywords) or split.item in (select KeywordFr from gs_Keywords)
        )
```

Comment: Perhaps you could just execute the SQL multiple times, keeping your string under the 4000 character limit, then join the results?

Comment: I could, I'd just like to know if there is an ideal solution where performance would be at its best.  There could be many records to run this against (it's a very large photo album) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2008, you can use a table-valued parameter to pass the list of keywords to the stored procedure.  You can use the variable like you would use a `table`, in  a `join` or an `in` clause.  For example:

```
use testdatabase
go
if exists (select * from sys.procedures where name = 'TestProc')
    drop procedure TestProc
if exists (select * from sys.types where name = 'TestProcList')
    drop type TestProcList
go
create type TestProcList as table (keyword varchar(50))
go
create procedure dbo.TestProc(
    @list TestProcList readonly)
as
select  *
from    YourTable
where   value in (select keyword from @list)
go
```

EDIT: if you have more than one keyword in the value field, you could use a [split function](http://geekswithblogs.net/AngelEyes/archive/2007/04/12/111504.aspx).  For example:

```
select  *
from    YourTable yt
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    dbo.fnSplit(yt.value, " ") split
        where   split.item not in (select keyword from @list)
        )
```

This demands that all keywords in the value column (separated by a space) are present in the `@list` parameter.

Comment: Oh, but I may have more than one keyword in the Value field, and this solution does not work in that case ...

Comment: I need at least 1 keyword in the Value field to be present in the Keyword table, but not all of them necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not well performing, but may be worth a try:

```
select * from MediaObjectsMetadata m
where exists 
(select null from Keywords k
 where m.values like '%' & k.KeywordEn & '%' or
       m.values like '%' & k.KeywordFr & '%' )
```

Comment: Does the LIKE keyword use FullText indicies if they exist?

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about having the stored procedure create a temp table of the contents of the column that contains the keyword, then seeing if there's any intersection between the UNION of the two lists and the temp table?

Is that something you know how to do (probably need a user defined function to split out the field to a table), and if not, what database backend are you using (sorry if there's something in the c# code that should tip me off, I don't see it)